# I bypassed servicestack to implement my own IHTTPHandler, but now I want access to the cache

Tags: servicestack

I have figured out how to bypass ServiceStack to implement my own HTTP Handler to serve files as a download, and it's working well.  I'm wondering, however, now that I'm outside servicestack, if I can somehow access the cache.

Below is how I'm registering my custom IHTTPHandler:

```
 SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
                {
                    RawHttpHandlers = new List<Func<IHttpRequest, IHttpHandler>>()
                    {
                        req => {
                            if (req.PathInfo.Contains("filetest"))
                                return new MP4DownloadHandler();
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Can I gain access to ServiceStack's cache (ICacheClient) from the ProcessRequest member of class MP4DownloadHandler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep you can access any of ServiceStack's dependencies via the singleton:

```
AppHostBase.Resolve<ICacheClient>();
```

Which looks at the IOC in the ASP.NET ServiceStack AppHost.

The same example that works in all ServiceStack AppHosts is:

```
EndpointHost.AppHost.TryResolve<ICacheClient>();
```